# Word meaning "without knowing the destination?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I've been following people [...] recently.

I'm looking for something similar to * aimlessly*. But instead of *not having a purpose* it should mean *not knowing the destination*.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a word that covers _following people without knowing where they will lead you_ except perhaps _blindly_ but that's maybe more to do with the _following_ than _where they are going_.

Comment: One _could_ use 'goallessly' - Wiktionary
adverb (not comparable). In a goalless manner. But the adjective is more usual. In your form, a single adverb would modify the following, not the people followed, and cannot really be used in place of an adverbial clause ('who do not know where they are headed').

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I'm reminded of Roger Zelazny's SF novel, 'The Dream Master'.  Set in a world where all vehicles are automatically controlled, some owners would get a buzz by randomly setting the co-ordinates of the destination.  It was called *blindspin*.

Comment: You might try " I've been following people *with no end in mind* recently". This could be adjusted to *no end in view/ no end in sight*.

Comment: "I've been **aimlessly** following people recently." (*aimlessly*: without definite aim, direction, rule, or method *wandered aimlessly through the forest until we were hopelessly lost* --MWO)

Comment: I suggest you stop doing that; you will likely be reported to the police as a stalker.

Comment: _Erratically_ perhaps. [ _erratic_: Having no fixed or regular course; wandering [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/erratically) ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard idiom for making decisions without important information is *blindly,* and it is frequently used in phrases such as "I am just following the crowd *blindly*" or "they just *blindly* followed orders."

Some caution might be in order, however.  While this idiom is quite common, it could arguably be considered offensive to those who are actually physically blind.

(Compare also military jargon for transmitting a message "[in the blind](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51564/meaning-of-the-term-in-the-blind)," meaning in the expectation that you can be heard, but without the ability to receive a message in return, as memorably used in the movie *Gravity.*)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to say you aren't selective in who you follow? If so:

Of late, I've been following people ***indiscriminately***.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this to enjoy the unplanned journey, you might try *serendipitously*.  *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/serendipitous)* defines *serendipitous* as

> Occurring or discovered by chance in a happy or beneficial way:
>   *a serendipitous encounter*

**Supplement**

Also consider *by [happenstance](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=happenstance)*

A chance circumstance: "I drove loops around the nearby parish school ... hoping to bump into her casually and claim it was mere happenstance" (Hart Seely).

*American Heritage*

It sounds like you are talking about *real* happenstance.

Answer (score 1):

- "I've been following people who **ramble** around town." or "I've been **rambling** around town, following people I never met."

> "ramble" (vb) -  "to walk or go from one place to another place without a specific goal, purpose, or direction." - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ramble), "to stroll about freely, with no particular direction [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ramble)

- "I've seen a few surprising scenes in my **rambles** in the country."
- "We **rambled** around town for six hours."

Comment: an excellent answer.well done!

Answer (score 1):

Coddiwomple (v.) Origin: English Slang Word - Definition: To travel in a purposeful manner towards a vague destination.

Peregrinate (v.) Origin: Latin -Definition: Travel or wander around from place to place.

http://hopscotchtheglobe.com/25-words-every-traveller-should-have-in-their-vocabulary/

Answer (score 0):

A journey without a destination simple means moving forward but in the wrong direction it means not knowing were you started but you continued in the journey which may lead you to the unknown

Comment: The OP was not asking about the meaning of the expression but for a word that means "not knowing one's destination"

Comment: Please answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Or if you are being a wanderer.

> I've been following people [**[rootlessly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rootlessly)**] recently.
>
> - rootlessly. having no ties to a particular locale. (wiki)

Comment: I think _root_ in this word refers to where you came from, not where you're located while you're doing it.